# Cannot Serialize error on Android

Tags: android, ksoap2

I need help. I'm trying pass parameters to webservice and it shows me an error:
**CANNOT SERIALIZE content_of_userText** . 
My code is:

```
if (button.getId() == R.id.loginButton) {

           //Modelo el request
           SoapObject request = new SoapObject(namespace, Metodo);

           //Paràmetres
           request.addProperty("correu", userText.getText());
           request.addProperty("pass", passText.getText());

           //Modelo el Sobre
           SoapSerializationEnvelope sobre = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
           sobre.dotNet = true;
           sobre.setOutputSoapObject(request);

           //Modelo el transporte
           HttpTransportSE transporte = new HttpTransportSE(url);

           try {       
               //Llamada
               transporte.call(accionSoap, sobre);

               //Resultado
               SoapObject resultado = (SoapObject) sobre.getResponse();

               Toast.makeText(this, resultado.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

           } 
           catch (Exception e)
           {
               Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
```

Thanks!!

EDIT: I try this:

request.addProperty("correu", userText.getText().toString());
request.addProperty("pass", passText.getText().toString());

and the exception now is:

**org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive**

EDIT2: It works! I change this:

```
SoapObject resultado = (SoapObject) sobre.getResponse();
```

for this:

```
String resultado = sobre.getResponse().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 request.addProperty("correu", userText.getText().toString());
 request.addProperty("pass", passText.getText().toString());
```

Instead of

```
   request.addProperty("correu", userText.getText());
   request.addProperty("pass", passText.getText());
```